# Access names of list elements in a loop

Tags: r

I have a list with named elements like so:

```
lst <- list(a1 = 5:12, b4 = c(34,12,5), c3 = 23:45)
```

I can easily retrieve the element names like so:

```
names(lst)
```

In a function I can loop over the list elements, but how can I access the name of the element that is being accessed in the loop:

```
test <- function(lst) {
  for (l in lst) {
    cat("The name of the current list element is", ???, "\n")
    # Other processing of the list element
  }
}
```

Comment: You can define the loop with `for (n in names(lst))` and use `n` in your call to `cat` and `lst[[n]]` to access the value of the corresponding element.  Though, as @zx8754 remarks, it would be better to use the `apply` family to process the list.

Comment: When working with with lists, use `*apply` functions, e.g.: `lapply(names(lst), function(i) doStuff(i))`

Comment: `purrr` provides some convenience functions for these actions, similar to @zx8754 mention of `*apply*`.  `purrr::imap(lst, ~ {cat("name is ", .y, "\n") ; .x + 1} )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `purrr` package, there are the functions `imap()` and `iwalk()`. They take a list and a function with two arguments and apply the function to every element of the list and its index/name. The difference is, that `iwalk` silently returns `NULL` and is executed only for side effects (helpful if you map over `cat()`) and `imap()` works similar to `lapply()` only it uses the functions second argument for the list's names.

```r
library(purrr)
lst <- list(a1 = 5:12, b4 = c(34,12,5), c3 = 23:45)

imap(lst,\(x,y) cat("The name of the current list element is", y, "\n"))
#> The name of the current list element is a1 
#> The name of the current list element is b4 
#> The name of the current list element is c3
#> $a1
#> NULL
#> 
#> $b4
#> NULL
#> 
#> $c3
#> NULL

iwalk(lst,\(x,y) cat("The name of the current list element is", y, "\n"))
#> The name of the current list element is a1 
#> The name of the current list element is b4 
#> The name of the current list element is c3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help

```
for (l in seq_along(lst)) {
  cat("The name of the current list element is", names(lst[l]), "\n")
  # Other processing of the list element
}
```

which gives

```
The name of the current list element is a1 
The name of the current list element is b4
The name of the current list element is c3
```

Comment: `names(lst)` can be taken out of the loop

Comment: @DonaldSeinen Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

`purrr`'s `imap` (and `iwalk`) are good functions if you want to access both data and the name of the list.

In base R, you may do this with any of the `apply` function which has been already mentioned in comments. Here's one using `Map` -

```
Map(function(x, y) sprintf('List name is %s and sum to %d', y, sum(x)), 
    lst, names(lst))

#$a1
#[1] "List name is a1 and sum to 68"

#$b4
#[1] "List name is b4 and sum to 51"

#$c3
#[1] "List name is c3 and sum to 782"
```